# What if somebody copies your signature on a contract that says you can't sue them?

Tags: contract-law, signature, forgery

What can the person do in such cases? And further more, what can the judge do to stop this paradox?

Comment: It's called fraud and if anything negative might happen, you get a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if somebody copies your signature on a contract that says you
>   can't sue them?
>
> what can the judge do to stop this paradox?

I will assume that by "*copying the signature*" you mean "*without the person's consent*". In that case, the contract is void and consequently *unenforceable*. However, it would need to be proved that the person whose signature was unlawfully used did not intend to be a party to that contract.

For a contract to be valid, the parties must have *knowingly* and *willfully* entered it, whether it is via a document or through their subsequent conduct/actions. False pretenses, identity theft, and akin offenses preclude these two essential requirements of any contract. Moreover, if the person who forged the signature is a party to the contract, then that unlawful act clearly contradicts the prerequisite "*covenant of good faith and fair dealing*" that is presumed in contracts.

The remedies or actionability available to a person whose signature has been forged depend on the laws of each jurisdiction.

Comment: Why do you believe that a party needs to enter into a contract "knowingly and willfully"?

Comment: @bdb484 how could a system of contract law work otherwise?

Comment: @phoog The way it works throughout common law: by relying on objective manifestations of assent, rather than unknowable subjective intentions.

Comment: @bdb484 I am (not) surprised You ask Me in terms of "my belief" on something basic like this. The legal def. of *contract* is based on terms such as *meeting of the minds*, *deliberate*, *agreement* (Black's Law Dict). If not entered *knowingly* and *willfully*, a contract could be stricken as fraud, hardship, coercion, or not consensual, not constructive, etc. *Manifestations of assent* implies being made *willfully* (unless provably coerced) and with knowledge (at least of what the party provably knew). Your reply to phoog reinforces my answer as to "*[parties'] subsequent conduct/actions*".

Comment: You are making a lot of unsupportable leaps here. How did the willfulness defense work out for the defendants in *Lucy v. Zehmer* and *Berry v. Gulf Coast Wings*?

Comment: @bdb484 Zehmer's defense was contradicted by evidence that he drafted the contract, amended it, signed it, and persuaded his wife to sign it as well. His pretext of "*bluff or dare to force Lucy to admit that he did not have $50,000*" was arguably a "bizarre defense", [84 S.E.2d 516, 520](https://www.leagle.com/decision/195460084se2d5161589); even Zehmer's counsel conceded at oral argument that "*Zehmer was not too drunk to make a valid contract*"; and evidence proved "*[execution of] a serious business transaction rather than a casual, jesting matter as defendants now contend*", *Id. at 521*.

Comment: I don't think you realize it, but you're slowly walking into my argument. Any thoughts on *Berry*?

Comment: @bdb484 I welcome people's genuine follow-up inquiries, but I learned not to entertain your endless jumping from one "challenge" to another as you are determined to "disagree" no-matter-what. I already addressed two of your comments or "inquiries" on this post. If you really need help understanding the difference between Toyota and "toy Yoda" in *Berry*, you can always ask the Law school of your choice. Bye bye.

Comment: Why so hostile to the Socratic method?

Answer (score 0):

A  fraudulent contract wouldn't be binding, but to take a different approach there's also the question of [consideration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration_in_English_law). What did you agree to receive in return for agreeing not to sue the other party, and can the other party show that you received it?

From the link :

> Consideration can be anything of value (such as an goods, money,
> services, or promises of any of these), which each party gives as a
> quid pro quo to support their side of the bargain. Mutual promises
> constitute consideration for each other.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration_in_English_law) If only one party offers
> consideration, the agreement is a "bare promise" and is unenforceable.

Possible jurisdictional question (the link refers to English Law), but English Common Law gets around...